# Strongly-Typed Model: How do I handle dropdown lists?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, html-select

I've created a partial view which represents the admin side of a blog.  In my model I've created a property and method shown below.

```
public int HeaderImage { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetHeaderImages() 
{
    List<SelectListItem> d = new List<SelectListItem>();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KineticBombardment"].ToString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id, imagepath from blogheaderimages",
            connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
                    item.Text = reader["id"].ToString();
                    item.Value = reader["imagepath"].ToString();

                    d.Add(item);
                }
            }

            return d;
        }
    }   
}
```

View:

```
<div class="input">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.HeaderImage,
        new SelectList(Model.HeaderImageList))
</div>
```

Now the whole goal was to use `GetHeaderImages()` to build the list, then store the selected value in the `HeaderImage` property and eventually save that to the DB.  Right now, the select list renders but instead of displaying text values, it displays the entire `System.Web.MVC.SelectListItem` object.

I guess the question I'm asking is: what's the ideal way for building a select list in a model (from a datasource), then populating another property in that model with the selected value?

Comment: pls vote up if the answer helped you

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right, but you have to tell the dropdown which field to display as text and witch to have as a value.

```
 <div class="input">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.HeaderImage,
           new SelectList(Model.HeaderImageList, "Value", "Text"))
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a select list. It just expects the items:

```
<div class="input">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.HeaderImage, Model.GetHeaderImages())
</div>
```